# '%2' being stripped on RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have rules on .htaccess that looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/services/service1/?$
RewriteRule . http://www.domain.com/Service1%20Services.html [R=301,L]
```

but the `%2` is being stripped and the end result is `http://www.domain.com/Service10Services.html`

I have searched and found that %2, just like %1 is a **[RewriteCond Backreference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)**.

My problem is I don't know how to escape it so that it would be treated as a string literal. Can someone please tell me how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Stupid suggestion #1: backslash?  Stupid suggestion #2: double percent?

Comment: tried both.. doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%2` is a special back-reference variable, you need to **escape it** to use it literally. Also you need `NE` flag for non encoding.

Use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^services/service1/?$ http://www.example.com/Service1\%20Services.html [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: ^ Internal Server Error (500) too if i use NE, if i did not use NE it results to `http://www.domain.com/Service1%2520Services.html`. sorry for the last comment above, it's incorrect because of the cache.

Comment: using NE makes error logs say '/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters'

Comment: WIth `NE` flag on I got final URI as `/Service1%20Services.html` but without `NE` I get `/Service1%2520Services.html` so `NE` is indeed needed here. What is your Apache version?

Comment: Apache Version 2.2.25

Comment: That is very strange, it should work. Did you put some extra space before NE?

Comment: holy cr*p it does matter. it works now **WITHOUT THE EXTRA SPACE**. thanks!

Comment: Yes space does matter, mod_rewrite is pretty rigid about them :)